# CSS keyframes not running in Safari 10.1 except when refocused

Tags: html, css, safari, css-animations

I have a keyframe animation that works in codepen, and works in my web page in every other browser but Safari (tested 10.1 and Tech Preview 27). Works in Chrome, Firefox.

It also works in Safari IF you switch to another tab and back again.

The SCSS is

```
.scroller {
  height: 160px;
  overflow: hidden;

  font-family: $font-family-ps-light;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 32px;
  line-height: 40px;
  color: #ecf0f1;

  &__container {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 40px;
    padding: 0 40px;



    &__text {
      display: inline;
      float: left;
      margin: 0;
    }

    &__list {
      margin-top: 0;
      padding-left: 140px;
      text-align: left;
      list-style: none;
      animation-name: change;
      animation-duration: 20s;
      animation-iteration-count: infinite;

      &__item {
        line-height: 40px;
        margin: 0;
      }
    }
  }
}


@keyframes change {
  0%, 12.66%, 100% {transform:translate3d(0,0,0);}
  16.66%, 29.32% {transform:translate3d(0,-25%,0);}
  33.32%,45.98% {transform:translate3d(0,-50%,0);}
  49.98%,62.64% {transform:translate3d(0,-75%,0);}
  66.64%,79.3% {transform:translate3d(0,-50%,0);}
  83.3%,95.96% {transform:translate3d(0,-25%,0);}
}
```

and the html

```
<div class="scroller">
        <div class="scroller__container">
          <div class="scroller__container__text">
          Now with
          </div>

          <ul class="scroller__container__list">
          <li class="scroller__container__list__item">more mapping</li>
          <li class="scroller__container__list__item">canvas design</li>
          <li class="scroller__container__list__item">maturity reporting</li>
          <li class="scroller__container__list__item">self-service support</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
```

A codepen of this is at http://codepen.io/smlombardi/pen/bqJJoq?editors=1100

Comment: I am having the exact same problem I guess, did you come up with a proper solution yet? I tried nearly everything... :(

Comment: no, I am afraid not.  very frustrating.  we decided to ignore the issue since most of our audience uses Chrome.